# Can't load correct information from file

Tags: c++, fstream

the problem with this bit of code is that it is not reading the .txt file correctly, I have provided a image of the .txt file while also providing the current output it is giving me. Any help would be welcomed.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
const int MAX_CHARS = 10;
const int MAX_STUDENTS = 1;
class File
{
public:
void openFile()
{
    ifstream input_file("UserPass.txt", ios::binary);
    if (input_file.fail())
    {
        cout << "Could not open file" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        if (!input_file.read((char*)&studLoaded, sizeof(studLoaded)))
        {
            cout << "Could not read file" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            streamsize bytesRead = input_file.gcount();
            if (bytesRead != sizeof(studLoaded))
            {
                cout << "Could not read expected number of bytes" << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                input_file.read((char*)&studLoaded, sizeof(studLoaded));
                input_file.close();
            }


        }
    }
};

void displayFile()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < MAX_STUDENTS; i++)
    {
        cout << "Username: " << studLoaded[i].username << endl;
        cout << "Password: " << studLoaded[i].password << endl;
        cout << "Verf ID:" << studLoaded[i].verfID << endl;
    }
}

private:

typedef struct
{
    char username[MAX_CHARS];
    char password[MAX_CHARS];
    int verfID;

}student_t;

student_t studLoaded[MAX_STUDENTS];
};
```

The main is just calling these functions

```
File f;
f.openFile();
f.displayFile();
```

This is what is in the .txt file [image]

This is the current output I have. i have tried numerous of things but I can't seem to get it to work. This is the current output I am getting.

[image]

Comment: Your file reader reads a binary file. If you provide a text file it won't read correctly. Have a look at this: [C++ FAQ: Serialization and Unserialization](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization) and specifically the answer to [How exactly do I read/write simple types in human-readable (“text”) format?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization#serialize-text-format)

Comment: In binary mode, you are just reading bytes. The input function doesn't care what the byte is, it's just 8-bits. So formatting characters like `'\n'` mean nothing special. It's just a byte with the value `0xa` that is read. If your input file is text (as you show) and you are concerned with information in separate *Lines*, then you need to use an input method that recognizes the `'\n'` as a separator (or at least as *whitespace*). So `>>` and `getline` are normal choices for reading in Plain-Old text mode.

Comment: *Format Note:* going forward do not post pictures of text, instead copy the text and paste it into your question (indented by 4-spaces so it formats in fixed width, or alternatively add lines above/below that consist of `\`\`\`` (3-backticks) which will format as fixed as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from my comment above, given the input file you show is a TEXT file, you don't want to read as `ios::binary`. Why? When reading binary input, all text formatting character have no special meaning. You are simply reading bytes of data, and `'\n'` (value: `0xa`) is just another byte in the stream. When reading text, you want to use the formatting characters in the text file to tell you when you have read a line or a word.

Further, as commented by [@sheff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7478597/scheff) were you to read in binary, it is up to you to know beforehand how many bytes you will read into `username` or `password` and where the `verfID` int is located in the stream. The link he provided gives a good explanation of the process [C++ FAQ: Serialization and Unserialization](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization). For writing binary data, especially when the data is in a `struct`, unless you serialize, there is no guarantee of portability between compilers due to where padding bits may be inserted into the struct.

So, unless you have a requirement to read and write in binary, you are better served reading a text file as text.

You can make the reading and outputting of your student data much simpler by overloading the `<<` and `>>` operators to read a students worth of data at a time from your input stream as text. For example to overload the `<<` operator to read a `student_t` worh of data, you can simply add a member function to your class:

```
    /* overload >> to read username, password, verfID from input stream */
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, passfile& pf)
    {
        student_t s {};     /* temporary struct student */

        /* attempt read of all 3 values (username, password, verfID) */
        if (is >> s.username >> s.password >> s.verfID) {
            /* handle storage of s here */
        }

        return is;  /* return stream state */
    }
```

The benefit of using the overloaded operators not only reduces the custom input functions to have to write, but will reduce your `main()` considerably. For example:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2) { /* verify at least 1 argument for filename */
        std::cerr << "error: password filename required.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    passfile pf (argv[1]);      /* declare instance of class, with filename */
    std::cout << pf;            /* output all student data */
}
```

To put the pieces of your class together, avoid using *fundamental types* such as `char[CONST]` and instead what the STL provides such as [std::string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (for your collection of `student_t` instead of a plain-old array of struct), etc. For your class, you will one additional container to force a unique `verfID`. You can write a function yourself to scan over all the collected `student_t` each time before insertion of a new student, or you can use [std::unordered_set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) to do it for you in a much more efficient way.

So using the STL containers, you would simply need a `std::vector<student_t>` for your student information storage (instead of an array) and you would use `std::unordered_set<int>` to hash your `verfID` and enforce uniqueness. Your class `private:` data members could be something like:

```
class passfile {

    struct student_t {
        std::string username {}, password {};   /* user std:string istead */
        int verfID;
    };

    std::unordered_set<int> verfID;         /* require unique verfID before add */
    std::vector<student_t> students {};     /* use vector of struct for storage */
    ...
```

For your `public:` members, you can use a constructor that takes the filename to read from as an argument, and then you would need only one helper-function in addition to the overloaded `<<` and `>>` operators. The helper-function just loops taking input with the overloaded `>>` operator until you reach the end of file.

Your constructors really don't need to be any more than:

```
  public:

    passfile() {}
    passfile (std::string fname) { readpwfile (fname); }
    ...
```

Your helper-function to repeatedly use the `>>` operator can be:

```
    void readpwfile (std::string fname)     /* read all students from filename */
    {
        std::ifstream f (fname);
        do
            f >> *this;                     /* use overloaded >> for read */
        while (f);
    }
    ...
```

The remaining details are handled by the overloaded `<<` and `>>` operators. Starting with the overload of `<<`, you really don't need it to do any more than loop over all students and output the data in the format you like, e.g.

```
    /* overload << to output all student data */
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const passfile& pf)
    {
        for (auto s : pf.students)
            os  << "Username: " << s.username << '\n' 
                << "Password: " << s.password << '\n' 
                << "Verf ID : " << s.verfID << "\n\n";

        return os;
    }
```

(**note:** the `friend` keyword in used in the declaration within the class, if you defined the function elsewhere, you would omit `friend` before the definition)

Your overload of `>>` is where most of the work takes place, though the logic is simple. You declare a temporary `student_t` to read values into from the stream. If that succeeds, you do a quick lookup in your unordered_set to see if the `verfID` is already present. If it isn't you add the `verfID` to your unordered_set, and add your temporary `student_t` to your vector and your are done. If the `verfID` is a duplicate, you can issue a warning or error, e.g.

```
     /* overload >> to read username, password, verfID from input stream */
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, passfile& pf)
    {
        student_t s {};     /* temporary struct student */

        /* attempt read of all 3 values (username, password, verfID) */
        if (is >> s.username >> s.password >> s.verfID) {
            /* if verfID not already in verfID unordered_set */
            if (pf.verfID.find (s.verfID) == pf.verfID.end()) {
                pf.verfID.insert (s.verfID);    /* add verfID to unordered_set */
                pf.students.push_back (s);      /* add temp student to vector */
            }
            else    /* warn on duplicate verfID */
                std::cerr << "error: duplicate verfID " << s.verfID << ".\n";
        }

        return is;  /* return stream state */
    }
```

Putting it altogether in a short example (which basically just adds the headers and closes the class for the information above), you would have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <unordered_set>

class passfile {

    struct student_t {
        std::string username {}, password {};   /* user std:string istead */
        int verfID;
    };

    std::unordered_set<int> verfID;         /* require unique verfID before add */
    std::vector<student_t> students {};     /* use vector of struct for storage */

  public:

    passfile() {}
    passfile (std::string fname) { readpwfile (fname); }

    void readpwfile (std::string fname)     /* read all students from filename */
    {
        std::ifstream f (fname);
        do
            f >> *this;                     /* use overloaded >> for read */
        while (f);
    }

    /* overload >> to read username, password, verfID from input stream */
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, passfile& pf)
    {
        student_t s {};     /* temporary struct student */

        /* attempt read of all 3 values (username, password, verfID) */
        if (is >> s.username >> s.password >> s.verfID) {
            /* if verfID not already in verfID unordered_set */
            if (pf.verfID.find (s.verfID) == pf.verfID.end()) {
                pf.verfID.insert (s.verfID);    /* add verfID to unordered_set */
                pf.students.push_back (s);      /* add temp student to vector */
            }
            else    /* warn on duplicate verfID */
                std::cerr << "error: duplicate verfID " << s.verfID << ".\n";
        }

        return is;  /* return stream state */
    }

    /* overload << to output all student data */
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const passfile& pf)
    {
        for (auto s : pf.students)
            os  << "Username: " << s.username << '\n' 
                << "Password: " << s.password << '\n' 
                << "Verf ID : " << s.verfID << "\n\n";

        return os;
    }
};

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2) { /* verify at least 1 argument for filename */
        std::cerr << "error: password filename required.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    passfile pf (argv[1]);      /* declare instance of class, with filename */
    std::cout << pf;            /* output all student data */
}
```

**Example Input File**

Using your input file above as a TEXT file:

```
$ cat dat/userpass.txt
Adam
Pass121
1
Jamie
abc1
2
```

**Example Use/Output**

Running the program and providing your input file as the first argument would result in:

```
$ ./bin/passwdfile dat/userpass.txt
Username: Adam
Password: Pass121
Verf ID : 1

Username: Jamie
Password: abc1
Verf ID : 2
```

If you needed to add more students by prompting the user for information, then all that would be needed is:

```
    std::cout << "enter user pass verfID: ";
    std::cin >> pf;
```

(try it, and try adding with a duplicate `verfID`...)

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions. Using the containers the STL provides is by far the better approach to take rather than trying to reinvent the wheel on your own (you eliminate a lot of errors that way...)