# Istream function to read with istream parameter

Tags: c++, function, class, ostream, istream

I'm trying to understand this code

```
istream &read(istream &is, Sales_data &item) 
{
    double price = 0;    
    is >> item.bookNo >> item.units_sold >> price;   
    item.revenue = price * item.units_sold;    
    return is;
} 

ostream &print(ostream &os, const Sales_data &item)
{
    os << item.isbn() << " " << item.units_sold << " "    
        << item.revenue << " " << item.avg_price();    
    return os; 
}
```

I don't understand what are these function ,  also I can't understand why we use `istream` for reading and `ostream` for printing instead of using `cin` and `cout`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] for an overview for our site.

Answer (score 4):

There are more than a few subtleties at play that you need to understand to understand what is taking place in the `read` and `print` functions. From the overview standpoint `istream` and `ostream` are general input and output classes that provide a basis for stream I/O in C++. As the other answer and comments correctly indicate, `std::cin` and `std::cout` are derived from `istream` and `ostream` to provide input/output from the standard stream `stdin` and `stdout`.

The stream themselves have a state that determines if the stream is good and can be read from or written to, or whether a stream error has occurred preventing further I/O (some failures are recoverable, some not) See [std::basic_ios::rdstate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdstate) and [std::basic_ios::setstate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/setstate) for a discussion of the bits (`goodbit, badbit, failbit, eofbit`) that make up the stream state.

Now looking at your function prototyes:

```
istream &read(istream &is, Sales_data &item)
```

and

```
ostream &print(ostream &os, const Sales_data &item)
```

Notice how the first parameter is a refernce to the current stream? And notice how the return is also a reference to that same stream? That's important, because it passes a reference to the stream so any changes to the *Steam State* occurring within the function will be available on return. So if `eof` is encountered within the `read` function, that change in state will be available on return. The same for your `print` function (though the potential errors that would change the stream are fewer and different)

Within `read`, you are reading 3-pieces of information from the stream, `item.bookNo, item.units_sold` and `price` and updating `item.revenue`:

```
is >> item.bookNo >> item.units_sold >> price; 
item.revenue = price * item.units_sold;
```

You can read from `std::cin` by passing that as the argument for `is` or you can pass an open file-stream. The stream operations will work for any valid stream.

The print function does the opposite, it outputs the return of `item.isbn(), item.units_sold, item.revenue` and the return from `item.avg_price()` as output. If you pass `std::cout` as `os`

The last command in both functions returns the stream including any change in the *stream state* so the caller can check whether the `read` or `print` was successful. That is key for the caller being able to determine whether the I/O took place.

**Overly Simplified Example**

An overly simplified example exercising the function may help the concepts sink in. Here we declare a simplified struct `Sales_data` with `int bookno, units_sold;` and `double price, revenue;` For example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Sales_data
{
    int bookno, units_sold;
    double price, revenue;
};
```

We then simplify `read` to read only the `bookno, units_sold` and `price` and compute the `revenue` for that single item, e.g.

```
std::istream &read(std::istream &is, Sales_data &item) 
{
    is >> item.bookno >> item.units_sold >> item.price;   

    item.revenue = item.price * item.units_sold;    

    return is;
}
```

And simplify `print` to only output the `units_sold` and `revenue`:

```
std::ostream &print(std::ostream &os, const Sales_data &item)
{
    os << "units sold: " << item.units_sold << " revenue: $"  << item.revenue << '\n';

    return os; 
}
```

Now you can see in a very simple way prompting the user to enter a `bookno, units_sold` and `price` how both the `read` and `print` functions work, as well as how an error occurring within one of the function changes the *stream state*. A short `main()` could be:

```
int main (void) {

    Sales_data sd;

    std::cout << "enter bookno units_sold price: ";

    if (read (std::cin, sd))        /* if read succeeds */
        print (std::cout, sd);      /* print data */
    else
        std::cerr << "error: invalid input\n";
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/readprintstream
enter bookno units_sold price: 12 100 12.95
units sold: 100 revenue: $1295
```

or if an error occurs:

```
$ ./bin/readprintstream
enter bookno units_sold price: 23 banannas 12.28
error: invalid input
```

Hopefully the discussion and example helps clear the concept up a bit. If you have further questions, let me know.

Comment: This example was very helpful!!! Things are more clear for me now. Thank you!

Comment: So basically that parameter istream &is is a reference for cin.(cin and &is are instances of istream)

Comment: Exactly. You are passing in whatever stream you want `read` to read from. In the case above it was `std::cin`, it could just as well have been an open file stream. You generally see this done with overloaded `<<` and `>>` operators rather than writing a `read` and `print` function, but either will do. See [Can't load correct information from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60245777/cant-load-correct-information-from-file) for a recent example of overloading `<<` and `>>`.

Answer (score 3):

`std::cin` and `std::cout` are specific instances of a `std::istream` and a `std::ostream`. Therefore, you could call these functions and pass `std::cin` or `std::cout` as the streams you want to use. This allows the functions to be more general-purpose, because we can use streams for more than just command line input and output.

In particular, `std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream` for file I/O and `std::istringstream` and `std::ostringstream` for string I/O.

Comment: "we can use streams for more than just command line input and output" in particular, `std::[i|o]fstream` for file I/O and `std::[i|o]stringstream` for string I/O.

Comment: Good clarification. I stole it and added it to my answer :)