# What's the use of "ostream &os"?

Tags: c++

I just started learning C++, and I saw some function in C++ primer like that:

```
double total_receipt(ostream &os)const{...}
```

then I try to find the address of `cout` by using this code: `"cout << &cout << endl;"`

and that's no difference between `ostream &os` and direct use `cout`.

So why not just use `cout` instead of `ostream &os`? Or maybe it's just a "good" habit?

Comment: This allows the function to be used to write to other streams (e.g. a disk file)

Comment: The first is the syntax for passing a parameter by reference. The second is the syntax for taking the address of an object. Sadly they are the same :-|

Comment: You may find [Istream function to read with istream parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60255516/istream-function-to-read-with-istream-parameter) useful. Understand `ostream& os` passes a *reference* to the file-stream as a parameter which allows the *stream-state* (See [std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>::rdstate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdstate) and [std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>::setstate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/setstate)) to be updated within the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First notice:

- `cout` is an object ([check these docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cout/))
- `ostream` is a class ([check these docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/ostream/))

When you declare a method, you need to use the class names for the parameters, so if your class uses an "output stream" (that's what `ostream` means) then you declare your function like:

```
double total_receipt(ostream &os)
```

You can't create the function like this:

```
double total_receipt(cout) // doesn't work
```

Now, if your question is about what is the difference between declaring the `total_receipt` function  like this:

```
double total_receipt(ostream &os) {
    os << "hello world" << std::endl;
}
```

or like this:

```
double total_receipt() {
    std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
}
```

That's up to you. Usually, we use the first one as that allows to invoke the function with other things besides `cout`, like:

```
ofstream out_file("my_file.txt");
total_receipt(out_file);
```

So, you can pass to that function any object of classes derived from `ostream`, like `ofstream` in the example. This means, your function can print to a file, besides printing to the terminal, so you add more functionality if you need it.